# Do performative utterances fix conditions of satisfaction?

Tags: philosophy-of-language

I recently listened to a lecture by John Searle regarding performative utterances, in which he argued that performative utterances require both a performative verb and extralinguistic information. For example, you can't say "I hereby persuade you," and a statement like "I pronounce you husband and wife" would only "work" if certain other conditions are met (such as the speaker being an officiant of some kind, the people involved being allowed to be married to each other, etc.).

It occurred to me, though: the action named in the verb is not necessarily the same as the effect. For example, with a statement like "I pronounce you husband and wife," you definitely made the pronouncement regardless of any extralinguistic information, so it succeeded in that narrow sense at least. The actual question is whether the statement had its intended effect (which is to cause them to actually be married).

Is my thought process a reasonable understanding of performative utterances, or am I missing something?

Also, is it correct to call the conditions under which the statement had its intended effect "conditions of satisfaction"? Or am I misunderstanding the term?

Comment: "I pronounce you man and wife" does not cause them to be married. It is the marrying itself. There are not two events, the speech act and its effects, but only one. As you discuss, uttering the words only marries people if the speaker is licensed to marry people. Without the license, uttering the words is just uttering the words. Take another example. When I fire the starting-gun, the starting of the race is not an effect of the sound. The sound is the beginning of the race. "I pronounce you..." is the beginning of the marriage.

Comment: @LudwigV That's a helpful distinction, I think I'm starting to see your point. Would the fact that they need a license fix a condition of satisfaction, or am I confused about that point?

Comment: Using John Austin's terminology, the utterance of the words is a locutionary act, the action performed in uttering the words is an illocutionary act, and the intended effect accomplished by the utterance is a perlocutionary act. So, saying, "I pronounce you man and wife" is a locutionary act, but it fails to be illocutionary unless it is said by the right person to the right people on the right occasion. All of those would be conditions of satisfaction.

Comment: Austin's analysis is a very good one, though not perfect. Searle is right, however. The issue raised here, I think, is whether a speech act _causes_ its intended (perlocutionaary) effect. I think not. I can persuade you to turn the volume down by saying the right, persuasive words. But I can't say "I hereby persuade you" so the effect is distinct from (caused by) the action. As officiant, I marry the two of you _in_ saying the right words, ("I hereby pronounce you..") so the effect is not distinct from the action. I assume that "conditions of satisfaction" means "conditions of success"?